# Change iTunes/iCloud Apple ID Primary email address

Tags: itunes, accounts

How do I change my email address on my iTunes account?

I opened my iTunes account at a job that I had 11 years. Now that I no longer have that email address, I would like to transfer it over to my new email address.
Can I do that or do I have to close my old account and open a new one?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to http://appleid.apple.com and click "Manage Your Apple ID" and after you login you can edit your primary email address. No need to create a new account. :)